# Flex mx:Tree - no itemRendererFunction ? How do I have different itemrenderers for items in a tree?

Tags: apache-flex, tree, itemrenderer

Why is there no itemRendererFunction for the mx:Tree?

How do I assign a different itemrenderer for different rows based on the items attributes?
thanks,

Comment: the mx components had no itemRendererFunction.  You'll have to make a single itemRenderer which can change the display / add hide components based on the data.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/treeClasses/TreeItemRenderer.html

Answer (score 0):

mx tree component has loads of known bugs...Once you start customising ..You will have loads of issues ..

Its better to create your own spark based tree ..

Check out this good example by Saturn Boy !! 
http://saturnboy.com/2011/09/spark-treelist/